# Regex expression for valid website link

Tags: regex

In my asp.net application, i need to validate the text for a valid website link. I want to use the regular expression validator for that. Anyone with any idea of how to validate the weblink user regex.

Answer (score 10):

try this -

```
^(?:ftp|http|https):\/\/(?:[\w\.\-\+]+:{0,1}[\w\.\-\+]*@)?(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+)|\?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+))?$
```

Explained each step below -

```
^                                   # Start at the beginning of the text  
(?:ftp|http|https):\/\/              # Look for ftp, http, or https  
(?:                                  # Username:password combinations (optional)    
  [\w\.\-\+]+                        # A username    
  :{0,1}                             # an optional colon to separate the username and password    
  [\w\.\-\+]*@                       # A password  
)?  
(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)                    # The domain limiting it to just allowed characters  
(?::[0-9]+)?                         # Server port number  
(?:                                  # The path (optional)    
  \/|                                # a forward slash    
  \/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+)| # or a forward slash followed by a full path    
  \?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+)  # or a question mark followed by key value pairs   
)?$
```

Comment: How about addresses like twitter.com or facebook.com ? Looks like your patter doesn't match it.

Answer (score 1):

```
|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i
```

Comment: Seems nice, but I wonder, does every sites always starts with http or https ?