# Regex to find a web address

Tags: regex

I'm trying to isolate links from html using a regex and the one I found that is suppose to do it doesn't seem to work.

```
/^(http?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

Am I missing something? I'm using Brackets as my text editor

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:http|https):\/\/(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+)|\?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&%@!\-\/\(\)]+))?$
```

Messy, but works.

Also, you might want to look at a similar question: [Regex expression for valid website link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726807/regex-expression-for-valid-website-link)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to make it 100% accurate.

A url could also be a IP address for example.

```
http://ip/
```

It can contain query strings.

```
http://www.google.com/?a=1&b=2
```

It can contain spaces.

```
http://www.google.com/this is my url/
```

It depends on what need you have for accuracy.